# Automatically subscribing and Fetching api response using Signals in Angular 16.1

Tags: angular, asynchronous, signals

This post is lengthy and might seem boring at times as I've tried to explain every bit of the situation.
I am hoping and trying my best that I am abiding the stackoverflow rules of asking a question
I'm only a 6 month old angular developer,  who really want to continue in this field
Since I got to know angular 16 was being released... signals were my topic of interest and recently I've had an amazing opportunity use it.

What I did:
For the past 7 days im hooked to my screen trying to work it. And I'm not achieving it. I've referred many youtube videos, even the documentation for quite a bit. Eventually finding nothing but there was video from a person in YouTube that was at least close to what I wanted but  since it was not exactly the way I wanted I ran into more issues, when I tried to use it.

What I want:
My requirements is very simple. In my newly created angular 16.1 project.  I have 3 roles and all of them are set up properly. Now I want to abstract away the api fetch response into a service. This is easily doable and we can return an observable or promise thereby completing the asynchronous operation. I do not want to do this. As a guy who had seen so many difficulties regarding the response being asynchronous in the previous projects that were created by someone else I want to make for myself and the future people easier looking code. And since I am using angular 16 which has the concept of signals I belive I can achieve this.

What I want codeWise:
I want to create an apiService which will be like

```
private fetchApiInService$ = this.http.get(this.url).pipe();

fetchApiInService = toSignal(fetchApiInService$)
```

Which I will use in my component as

```
fetchApiInComponent;
ngOnInit(){
this.fetchApiInComponent = this.apiService.fetchApiInService();
}
```

currently this will return undefined, but according to the signals concept, when the data is updated in the fetchApiInService it is supposed to send a notification to the interested subscriber that is fetchApiInComponent. Signals will automatically subscribe and unsubscribe for us. But it is still giving me undefined.

Thanks.
I know I am probably doing a rookie mistake and you might have already seen the exact same mistake somewhere else here. Please show some mercy and guide me through so that I can make anyone else after me and my life easier regarding using this.
In the case question seems duplicated please link the other question. As I have seen many already where I searched by giving "fetch, signals, angular" and "signals in angular" and went through each question one by one for at least 5 pages and none really match the exact query I have, thus making it difficult to understand.
I am trying to abide the stackoverflow rules of asking a question so I request anyone to not lock or block it until we get a proper solution.

Thank you in Advance

Edit : I learnt that you have to first return in map first `private fetchApiInService$ = this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map((res)=>{return res}));` then i had to call the reference as so `this.fetchApiInComponent = this.apiService.fetchApiInService` not the function itself

but this good for http.get but how do i do for post ?
also i got the error for { requireSync : true} it will pass error if the observable is not already emitting data, this is not what i require

Comment: I think, you can try to set { requireSync: true }

Comment: Thanks for replying, Thanks for replying I've just searched you do this by putting it in toSignal(fetchApiInService, {requireSync : true}), this will mean that signal will always have data .. but does this mean that signal will always have data until observable emits the data ?